# copy and paste part of the tab-type data to create new document

Tags: python, copy, copy-paste

I have a set of tab-type data to clean up for my research. Each dataset is not in the typical neat column-by-column format, but in the tab format by each individual county (as shown below)

```
1CURRENT DATE: XXX               AGE,SEX, RACE AND ETHNICITY OF PERSONS  PAGE    1
 BEGINNING DATE FOR DATA TOTALS: 01/83                    COUNTY    001
 ENDING DATE FOR DATA TOTALS: 12/83                                                                       RECORD COUNT    36
              Gender     Age_20    Age_21     Age_22   Age_23    Asian    Hispanic    White
Robbery       F           1          2          2        2         3         3          3
              M           3          3          2        2         4         3          3
Fraud         F           1          2          2        2         3         3          2
              M           2          3          2        2         4         3          3  
Arson         F           1          2          2        2         3         3          3
              M           4          3          2        2         4         3          4

1CURRENT DATE: XXX               AGE,SEX, RACE AND ETHNICITY OF PERSONS  PAGE    4
 BEGINNING DATE FOR DATA TOTALS: 01/83                    COUNTY    002
 ENDING DATE FOR DATA TOTALS: 12/83                                                                       RECORD COUNT    36
              Gender     Age_20    Age_21     Age_22   Age_23    Asian    Hispanic    White
Robbery       F           1          2          2        2         3         3          3
              M           2          3          2        2         4         4          3
Fraud         F           1          2          2        2         3         3          2
              M           2          3          2        2         4         6          3  
Arson         F           1          2          2        2         3         3          3
              M           4          3          2        2         4         3          4

1CURRENT DATE: XXX               AGE,SEX, RACE AND ETHNICITY OF PERSONS  PAGE    7
 BEGINNING DATE FOR DATA TOTALS: 01/83                    COUNTY    003
 ENDING DATE FOR DATA TOTALS: 12/83                                                                       RECORD COUNT    36
              Gender     Age_20    Age_21     Age_22   Age_23    Asian    Hispanic    White
Robbery       F           1          2          2        2         3         3          3
              M           3          3          2        2         4         3          3
Fraud         F           1          2          1        4         3         3          2
              M           2          3          2        2         4         3          3  
Arson         F           1          2          4        2         3         3          3
              M           4          3          2        2         4         3          4
```

I cannot directly import these datasets into excel or stata for further analysis due to its tab-type nature. What I plan to do is to copy and paste the ID of each county (i.e: COUNTY 003, COUNTY 002, etc) and a specific type of crime to create a new column-like dataset as this:

```
              Gender     Age_20    Age_21     Age_22   Age_23    Asian    Hispanic    White    County
Robbery       F           1          2          2        2         3         2          3        001
Robbery       F           1          2          2        2         2         3          3        002
Robbery       F           1          2          2        2         3         3          3        003
```

and further clean the data from this new dataset.

I searched online and found that Python can actually do this kind of copy and paste of specific part of the file to new document. But I am really new to Python, my experience is mainly in Stata and SPSS. I do not know exactly which codes will perform this type copy-and-paste job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).  The specifics will vary depending on your format, but massaging your data into something cleaner doesn't take much.  There are prettier, less hardcoded ways to do the following, but here's an example almost stream-of-consciousness:

```
import pandas as pd

# read in a fixed-width file
df = pd.read_fwf("crime.tsv", widths=[14] + [10]*8, header=None)
# clean up the strings
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, basestring) else x)

# make a new column
df["County"] = None
# move over the county information
df["County"][df[5] == "COUNTY"] = df[6]
# fill the county info forwards into the empty places
df["County"].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

# fill the crime information forwards
df[0].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

# reset the columns from one of the examples
df.columns = ["Crime"] + list(df.ix[3,1:-1]) + ["County"]
# get rid of any of the headings left in the table
df = df[~(df["Gender"] == "Gender")]

# toss anything which still has empty cells
df = df.dropna()

# reset the index, and fix the types
df = df.set_index(["Crime", "Gender", "County"]).astype(int)
df = df.reset_index()
```

which produces

```
>>> df
      Crime Gender County  Age_20  Age_21  Age_22  Age_23  Asian  Hispanic  White
0   Robbery      F    001       1       2       2       2      3         3      3
1   Robbery      M    001       3       3       2       2      4         3      3
2     Fraud      F    001       1       2       2       2      3         3      2
3     Fraud      M    001       2       3       2       2      4         3      3
4     Arson      F    001       1       2       2       2      3         3      3
5     Arson      M    001       4       3       2       2      4         3      4
6   Robbery      F    002       1       2       2       2      3         3      3
7   Robbery      M    002       2       3       2       2      4         4      3
8     Fraud      F    002       1       2       2       2      3         3      2
9     Fraud      M    002       2       3       2       2      4         6      3
10    Arson      F    002       1       2       2       2      3         3      3
11    Arson      M    002       4       3       2       2      4         3      4
12  Robbery      F    003       1       2       2       2      3         3      3
13  Robbery      M    003       3       3       2       2      4         3      3
14    Fraud      F    003       1       2       1       4      3         3      2
15    Fraud      M    003       2       3       2       2      4         3      3
16    Arson      F    003       1       2       4       2      3         3      3
17    Arson      M    003       4       3       2       2      4         3      4
```

after which we can do all sorts of neat things.

Comment: Hey DSM, thank you very much for your answer. I just found out that some datasets have tabs with different variable_names in the same file. e.g, some tabs have ages and ethnicity as the ones in my example. Some other tabs with locations. Since they don't share the same variable names, but in the same columns, I cannot directly apply your codes to the file. Still have to first save those tabs with only ages and ethnicity and then apply your code. Can you provide some hints of how to isolate those tabs with only ages&ethnicity from those tabs with locations? Thank you very much in advance